# openerp server Import error: there is no module named gevent

Tags: odoo, openerp-7

I have installed Im module in my system(windows7) and I am trying to start server through

command line using `openerp-server --gevent` but getting below error

```
C:\Program Files\OpenERP 7.0-20140118-002423\Server\server>openerp-server --gevent
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "openerp-server", line 2, in <module>
  File "C:\Program Files\OpenERP 7.0-20140118-002423\Server\server\.\openerp\__init__.py", line 40, in <module> import cli  File "C:\Program Files\OpenERP 7.0-20140118-002423\Server\server\.\openerp\cli\__init__.py", line 3, in <module>    import geventImportError: No module named gevent
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [unable to start openerp-server --gevent](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22504410/unable-to-start-openerp-server-gevent)

Answer (score 5):

just install it.

```
sudo pip install gevent
```